# Verbs to use with tattoo

Tags: word-choice, verbs

Which verbs do you use with tattoes and is adding "tattoo" after each word required, I mean "a mermaid tattoo", "a star tattoo" "a flower tattoo"?
"I like getting different tattoes. I have a small mermaid on my left shoulder, a star on my neck and a flower on my arm."

Comment: Once you have established that you are talking about tattoos, there is no need to repeat it. It is not clear what you mean by **which verbs**.  People **get** a tattoo or **have** a tattoo. or have an image **tattooed** on to their bodies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tattoo is itself a verb.  "I tattoo people for a living".  "I tattooed myself with a star last night".

It is also a noun so many other verbs can be used in combination with tattoo when it is used as a noun.  "I got a tattoo".  "I like tattoos".

It is not necessary to include tattoo after each word so long as the meaning is clear.  Your example "I like tattoos. I have a mermaid, a star and a flower" is fine.  Without the first sentence, or any other indication what you were talking about, it would be confusing.